# SQL: Declaring multiple variables that will not all be used at the same time

Tags: sql, sql-server, dynamic-sql

I'm writing a query that multiple variables will need to be set for but not all used at the same time. It looks something like this.

```
 Declare @SuveryID as Int 
 Declare @StateAbbrev as Varchar
 Declare @InvStart as Date
 Declare @InvEnd as Date
 Set @SuveryID = ''
 Set @StateAbbrev = ''
 Set @InvStart = ''
 Set @InvEnd = ''
```

What I'm wanting it to do is whenever survey ID has a value in it, the others will be ignored. And whenever `@StateAbbrev`, `@InvStart`, and `@InvEnd` have a value, `@SurveryID` is ignored.

Comment: Make sure to [give that `VARCHAR` a length](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/09/bad-habits-to-kick-declaring-varchar-without-length).

Comment: You might also consider not initializing the variables (especially an INT or DATE to empty string).  Empty string is still a value.

Comment: ignored by what?   what if all of them have values?   When would these values be assigned?   why did you tag `dynamic-sql`?

Answer (score 3):

One way would be like...

```
if @SuveryID  is null
begin
   select *
   from YourTable
   where <all your other variables>
end
else
begin
   select *
   from YourTable
   where Column = @SuveryID  
end
```

Another way would be to set the variables to `NULL` when `@SuveryID is not null` and then use a catch all query. These are called [Kitchen Sink](https://blogs.sentryone.com/aaronbertrand/backtobasics-updated-kitchen-sink-example/) queries and that article from Aaron Bertrand is worth a read for sure.

```
if @SuveryID  is not null
begin
   set @StateAbbrev  = null
   set @InvStart  = null
   <set all other variables to null>
end

select *
from YourTable
where (Column = @SuveryID or @SuveryID is null)
and   (Col2 = @StateAbbrev or @StateAbbrev  is null)
and   <continue for all variables>
```

Comment: Thank you! This helps a ton!